# pass arguments to a d3 on "click" event callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my code:

```
function toggleClass(element, className){
  d3.select(element).classed(className, !d3.select(element).classed(className));
}

d3.selectAll("rect").on("click", toggleClass(this, "clicked");
```

I cannot get it to work, it appears that passing arguments to a DOM event is bad news bears. Does anyone know a work-around for this?

Thank you

Comment: You can use an anonymous function to do this: `.on('click', function() { toggleClass(this, "clicked"); })`

Comment: Arguments are always evaluated before they are passed to a function. So if you have `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is executed first and its *return value* is passed to `foo`. If you want to pass a callback, you have to *pass* a function, not *call* a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
function toggleClass(element, className){
  d3.select(element).classed(className, !d3.select(element).classed(className));
}

d3.selectAll("rect").on("click", function () {
  toggleClass(this, "clicked");
});
```

here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g45Ju/

thanks to jshanley

Comment: This strategy helped me pass in arguments to a function I needed to call, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `selection.datum()` function? This snippet might give you an idea :

```
d3
 .select('svg')
 .append('circle')
 .datum({
    'x':10,
    'y':100,
    'z':100
  })
 .on('click'),function(d){
     //Here d = {'x':10,'y':100,'z':1000}
  });
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much. I was searching since 2-3hours for a solution